# Compile a Rcpp package with line information in the debugging symbols

Tags: r, debugging, gdb, rcpp, debug-symbols

I can’t figure out how to give my R package’s shared library’s debug symbols source line information. What am I missing?

1. I create the following `src/Makevars` file:

   ```
   PKG_CXXFLAGS=-O0 -ggdb
   PKG_LIBS=-O0 -ggdb
   ```
2. I compile the package using `R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source`:

   ```
   * installing to library ‘~/.local/lib/R/3.6’
   * installing *source* package ‘reticulate’ ...
   ** using staged installation
   g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R/" -DNDEBUG  -I"$HOME/.local/lib/R/3.6/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O0 -ggdb -fpic  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
   ** libs
   g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -o reticulate.so RcppExports.o event_loop.o libpython.o output.o python.o readline.o -O0 -ggdb -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
   ```

   installing to ~/.local/lib/R/3.6/00LOCK-reticulate/00new/reticulate/libs
3. I debug like this:

   ```
   R -d gdb --slave -e 'reticulate::py_eval("print")()'
   GNU gdb (GDB) 8.3
   [...]
   (No debugging symbols found in /usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R)
   (gdb) break py_get_formals
   Function "py_get_formals" not defined.
   Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
   Breakpoint 1 (py_get_formals) pending.
   (gdb) run
   Starting program: /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R --slave -e reticulate::py_eval\(\"print\"\)\(\)
   [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
   Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
   [...]
   Thread 1 "R" hit Breakpoint 1, 0x00007fffeb6b79a0 in py_get_formals(PyObjectRef, bool) () from /home/angerer/.local/lib/R/3.6/reticulate/libs/reticulate.so
   (gdb) step
   Single stepping until exit from function _Z14py_get_formals11PyObjectRefb,
   which has no line number information.
   [...]
   ```

Why does my function not have line numbers even though I specified `-ggdb` in both compilation? I see that only `RcppExports.cpp` is mentioned in the command line, is that the problem? If so, how can I change this?

Comment: To compile all the sources you should use `R CMD build` + `R CMD INSTALL` on the resulting tarball. Alternatively `R CMD INSTALL --preclean` can help. However, you should also look into removing the `-O2` by setting `CXXFLAGS`, `CXX11FLAGS` via `~/.R/Makevars`.

Comment: I have the same problem, setting debug and optimisation flags in `src/Makevars` is overwritten by "global" definitions like in `~/.R/Makevars` but I don't want to modify `~/.R/Makevars` since it has an impact on packages I compile or install in the future. How can I isolate these settings for my package only?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Makevars doesn’t prompt recompilation.

I needed to `rm -f src/*.o src/*.so` before the object files get recompiled.

Comment: You rediscovered what the `Make` language and its `Makefile` do.  And why many of us use an optional file `cleanup` which, if present, is called by `R CMD *` as well.

Comment: The first part is just condescending: I’ve been (decreasingly) using make for 10 years, and expected changes in `Makevars` to invalidate all compilation targets as it should be. The second part is a hack around the lack of this behavior that should be mentioned in tutorials.

Comment: It is explained in _Writing R Extensions_.

Comment: Where? It says something that implies the opposite: “If the configure script creates files, e.g. src/Makevars, you do need a cleanup script to remove them.”

Comment: Which is what I told you on Aug 9: "many of us use an optional file `cleanup`".

Comment: That means everything gets rebuilt every time, right? Sane default behavior would be that things get rebuilt once their source files change and everything gets rebuilt if the Makevars file changes.

Comment: No, if you build from a source directory, say your repo, that is exactly what is happening: incremental builds, and _not_ everything.  The `cleanup` script gets invoked when you build a `tar.gz` and/or when you call it explicitly.  Which _e.g._ I do after I changed compilation flags.  Also, look into `ccache`. It too knows when to recompile, and when to fetch from cache. Very handy.

Comment: @flyingsheep Which `Makevars` did you change? The file in `src` or `~/.R`?

Comment: The file in src. Respecting the other one (by keeping a cache of the last used build options) would be possible too but a bit harder than the trivial “add src/Makevars to the dependency glob”

Comment: Can anyone comment on where this file should be on Windows 10? I have tried putting the vars file in Users/<username>/.R/Makevars.win. That did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is specifically for Windows. The simplest way to do it is to set the R_MAKEVARS_USER environment to point to the Makevars.win file. That seems to work. However, debug break points have stopped working!!!!